# Add class properties in list and View in loop

Tags: c#-4.0

I have class 'Product' with three properties. It simple console application where user gives three records and it goes in list. I create list from class product but some reason its going to infinite entry! I don't know what I am doing wrong

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
  class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product obj1 = new Product();         
    }
  }

 class Product
 {     
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Product Name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Product Price: ");
        string price = Console.ReadLine();

        List<Product> MyList = new List<Product>();

        MyList.Add(new Product() { ID = 1, Name = name, Price = price });

        foreach(var item in MyList)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("ID "+item.ID + " Name "+item.Name);

    }
 } //end product class
}
```

Comment: Don't invoke a constructor from the same constructor. You should remove all from this constructor and provide a second that takes a Name and a Price. Then you can initialize the properties with these arguments.

Comment: I think reading from console in the constructor is really bad design,,, I see such a stuff first time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
         {
        List<Product> MyList = new List<Product>();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Product Name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine(); 

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Product Price: ");
            string price = Console.ReadLine();

    MyList.Add(new Product{ ID = 1, Name = name, Price = price });

    foreach(var item in MyList)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("ID "+item.ID + " Name "+item.Name);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("End of Program; Press Enter to Exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Product
{     
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Price { get; set; }

   public Product()
   {   
   }
} //end product class
}
```

You generally don't have UI interaction within a data class.

Might I suggest you work through [Rob Miles Yellow Book](http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/Rob%20Miles%20CSharp%20Yellow%20Book%202011.pdf), it is a good book for learning how to program C# for the first time.

Comment: It would be part of the Program class.

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor you create a new Product, theres your loop

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for Product you are creating a new Product, which will in turn call the constructor for Product, which will create yet another Product.
In other words its an infinite loop!